# Memory leak in Parse.com Android SDK v 1.5.1

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, parse-platform

I am saving a ParseFile (image) with a ParseObject. 
ParseObjects are saved in Parse's local data store using pinning. 
 When internet connection becomes available the App uploads the ParseObjects first. Then all images are uploaded one at a time. All uploads are tracked via save_callbacks. 
Within a ParseFile's save success callback I update the ParseObject with the files reference i.e parseObject.put("image", parseImageFile) and then call save on the object. 
There is a memory leak at parseObject.put. Within the callbacks I have tried setting everything to null to get rid lingering reference i.e i set the image byte array, parsefile, parseobject to null but this has not helped. The parse offlinestore keeps references to the ParseObject, PArsefile, byte[].
 I have also tried removing the reference in the save_callback with parseObject.put("image", null) which causes an ANR. I have tried to remove the reference using parseobject.remove("image"), tried replacing the parsefile ref with a smaller memory footprint by calling parseobject.put("image", "ABC".getBytes()) but none of these methods has worked to resolve the leak. Needless to say eventually I get an OutOfMemory Exception.

PS- Assuming this might due to an internal parse cache i have also tried calling ParseQuery.clearAllCachedResults().

 Below are 3 screenshots of the dalvik heap analyzed in Eclipse MAT. 
Anyone had a similar issue?

[image: This is leak suspects list obtained using Eclipse MAT]
[image: Dalvik Memory Heap]
[image: incoming references to byte array holding the image]

Comment: For progress follow corresponding bug report on Facebook bugs portal: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/551646974981894/

Comment: Acknowledged as bug. They are working on patch